# How to detect when button is pressed second time in function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writting a code on Raspberry Pi in Python3 to control a door opening. I have a code that is triggered by button being pressed and it works fine. Later in the code I want to take some additional actions when the same button is pressed again and this is not working.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

```
#/usr/bin/python3

def read_code():
    kod = ''
    klawisz = ''     
    for event in dev.read_loop():
        if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
            e = categorize(event)
            if e.keystate == e.key_down:
                klawisz = e.keycode[4:]
                if klawisz != "ESC":
                    kod = (kod + klawisz)
                    print(kod)
                else:
                    break
    return kod

while True:
    button_state = GPIO.input(Button)
    if button_state == 0:
        print('TYPE CODE')
        while read_code() !='1234':
            GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
            print('WRONG CODE')
        else:
            print('CODE IS CORRECT')
       /// trying to detect button being pressed again but not working///
            button_state2 = GPIO.input(Button)
            if button_state2 == 0:
            print('TYPE CODE')
            while read_code() !='5678':
                GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
                print('WRONG CODE')
            else:
                print('CODE IS CORRECT')

    else:
        GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: The Raspberry Pi has a button and the flow I want to have is:    Button pressed -> start program, do some stuff -> button pressed again -> do more stuff

Comment: You code needs to check that the button has been released before looking for it to be pressed again.

Comment: Hi Barnym yes you were right on button release. I found a nice discussion and another solution for this which works great for me.                  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96424